# Prisoner's dilemma as a Bayesian one-shot game

Tags: game-theory, nash-equilibrium, bayesian-game

What happens if we assume that there is incomplete information to the prisoner's dilemma game?

For example, suppose we have the following matrix with the utilities $T>R>P>S$ and $2R>S+T$ with only $2$ players and $2$ actions.

[image]

With $\Theta_i=\{\underline{\theta},\bar{\theta}\}$, does this mean that we have $2$ subgames (ex-interim) where we fix player $1$'s type and assign probabilities to player $2$'s types? Is this is the correct way to analyze the game?

If there is a paper studying the one-shot Prisoner's dilemma as a Bayesian game, I'd appreciate it very much if you share it with me!

Thank you.

Comment: If the types don't affect the payoffs, then there's no change in the predicted outcome.

Comment: I found this blog related to one-shot Prisoner's dilemma online.
https://www.schneier.com/blog/archives/2013/05/one-shot_vs_ite.html

Comment: @HerrK. But usually in a Bayesian game, we define the utility functions as $u:\Theta\times A\to\mathbb{R}$, where $\Theta$ is the type space and $A$ is the action space. My point is that the types will necessarily affect the payoffs, right?

Comment: @johnny09: Yes. But how do types affect payoffs in your case? How do $P,R,S,T$ change when $\theta$ changes?

Comment: @HerrK. Maybe I didn't write my question precisely, but I am more worried about the equilibrium analysis of such a game where types affect the utilities, eg we have $(R+\underline{\theta},R+\bar{\theta})$ instead of simply $(R,R)$.

Comment: @johnny09: I'm not sure what you're worried about. Equilibrium in Bayesian games like the one you propose is a well understood concept. Players mutually best respond to each other's strategy in the presence of uncertainty. Perhaps you should be more precise about what your problem is.

Comment: @HerrK.Would it be possible if you share a reference justifying your claim "well-understood concept"? As I wrote in my question, I don't know how to analyze the game so, I am interested in seeing a rigorous solution.

Comment: @johnny09: Sorry I didn't get pinged for your last comment. The graduate micro text by Mas-Colell, Whinston and Green is a good reference. Bayesian games and the associated Bayesian Nash equilibrium is introduced on page 255.